# Copy data in a table without auto incremented column in oracle

Tags: oracle, create-table

I have copied the table from my local database to production database. But what here happened is my auto incremented column value has also been copied. I dont want that.

Here my auto incremented column  is `RRSOC_ID` in table `TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO`.

So what should I do now that it get copied without that column. I tried like this but data is not getting copied.

`create table TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO1 as ( select * from TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO where 1=0);`

Below is my table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE "APP_WFM"."TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO" 
  ( "RRSOC_ID" NUMBER, 
"STORE_CODE" NVARCHAR2(55), 
"STATE" NVARCHAR2(55), 
"CITY" NVARCHAR2(55), 
"SITE_STORE_FORMAT" NVARCHAR2(155), 
"STORE_SITENAME" NVARCHAR2(255), 
"STORE_SITENAME_LANDL_1" NVARCHAR2(155), 
"STORE_SITENAME_LANDL_2" NVARCHAR2(155), 
"STORE_ASST_MANAGER_NAME" NVARCHAR2(155), 
"STORE_ASST_MANAGER_MOBNO" NVARCHAR2(100), 
"STORE_MANAGER_NAME" NVARCHAR2(155), 
"MANAGER_MOBNO" NVARCHAR2(100), 
"EMP_NEAREST_STORE" NVARCHAR2(155), 
"EMP_NEAREST_STORE_MOBNO" NVARCHAR2(100), 
"SUPERVISOR_NAME" NVARCHAR2(155), 
"SUPERVISOR_MOBNO" NVARCHAR2(155), 
"SECURITY_SUP_NAME_STORE" NVARCHAR2(155), 
"SECURITY_SUP_MOBNO_STORE" NVARCHAR2(155), 
"NAME_ALIGNED_LPO" NVARCHAR2(155), 
"LPO_MOBILENO" NVARCHAR2(100), 
"ALPM_ALPO_NAME" NVARCHAR2(155), 
"ALPM_ALPO_MOBNO" NVARCHAR2(155), 
"AREA_MANAGER_NAME" NVARCHAR2(155), 
"AREA_MANAGER_MOBNO" NVARCHAR2(155), 
"ZONAL_HEAD_NAME" NVARCHAR2(155), 
"ZONAL_HEAD_NO" NVARCHAR2(155), 
"DVR_IP_ADDRESS" NVARCHAR2(255), 
"SIGNET_IP_ADDRESS" NVARCHAR2(155), 
"NEAREST_POLICE_STN_NAME" NVARCHAR2(255), 
"NEAREST_POLICE_STN_CONTNO" NVARCHAR2(255), 
"NEAREST_HOSP_NAME" NVARCHAR2(255), 
"NEAREST_HOSP_CONTNO" NVARCHAR2(255), 
"NEAREST_FIRE_STN_CONTNAME" NVARCHAR2(255), 
"NEAREST_FIRE_STN_CONTNO" NVARCHAR2(255), 
"STORE_SPACE_SQFT" NVARCHAR2(155), 
"STORE_ADDRESS" NVARCHAR2(555), 
"LAUNCH_DATE" DATE, 
"CST_TIN_NO" NVARCHAR2(55), 
"STORE_EMAILID" NVARCHAR2(155), 
"NO_OF_POS" NVARCHAR2(155), 
"NO_OF_CAMERA" NVARCHAR2(155), 
"DVR_MODEL_GESECURITY" NVARCHAR2(155), 
"CAMERA_MODEL" NVARCHAR2(155), 
"ALIGNED_LPO_MAILDID" NVARCHAR2(155), 
"FACILTY_TEAMNAME" NVARCHAR2(155), 
"FACILITY_TEAMNO" NVARCHAR2(155), 
"STATE_HEAD_OPS_NAME" NVARCHAR2(255), 
"STATE_HEAD_OPS_NO" NVARCHAR2(355), 
"LPA" NVARCHAR2(255), 
"SLP_STATE_HEAD" NVARCHAR2(255), 
"SLP_STATE_HEAD_NO" NVARCHAR2(255), 
"CREATED_BY" NVARCHAR2(255), 
"CREATED_DATE" DATE, 
"LAST_UPDATED_BY" NVARCHAR2(155), 
"LAST_UPDATED_DATE" DATE, 
"ISACTIVE" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
"LATITUDE" NVARCHAR2(100), 
"LONGITUDE" NVARCHAR2(100), 
"DELETED_BY" NVARCHAR2(255)
 ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
 STORAGE(INITIAL 81920 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
 TABLESPACE "APP_WFM" ;
```

Comment: `mysql` or `oracle`?

Comment: @TomJMuthirenthi: sorry my mistake. its `oracle`

Comment: Why aren't you just listing out the columns you do want, instead of using `select *`?

Comment: @AlexPoole: i have more than 50 columns so shd i add each column name..

Comment: Yes, you should have already done that. Avoid "SELECT * FROM" anywhere you can (and that's, basically, everywhere, except for quick testing purposes).

Comment: @AlexPoole: can u show how to add it. please ?

Comment: Do you want the new table to not have the `RRSOC_ID` column at all, or to have the column but with all values set to null (or some other value)? If the latter you can just update the table after copying

Comment: @AlexPoole: except `RRSOC_ID` column i want all the data to be get copied in my new table. because my `RRSOC_ID` column is auto incremented

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
select * from TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO where 1=0
```

will create the table with the same columns and data types are the original, but with no data. No rows in the source table will ever match `where 1=0`, but the metadata for the result set is still determined, and is used for the new table creation in the CTAS statement.

If you want to create the new table without one of the columns you can list the ones you *do* want explicitly:

```
create table TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO1 as
select STORE_CODE, STATE, CITY, ...
from TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO;
```

If you want to include that column but not its values you can include it with a dummy value:

```
create table TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO1 as
select cast(null as number) as RRSOC_ID, STORE_CODE, STATE, CITY, ...
from TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO;
```

If you have an issue listing all the columns you can generate that from the data dictionary, e.g.:

```
select 'create table TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO1 as select '
  || listagg(column_name, ',') within group (order by column_id)
  || ' from TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO;'
from user_tab_columns
where table_name = 'TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO'
and column_name != 'RRSOC_ID';
```

and then run the statement that generates (after checking it, of course).

Alternatively you can copy the entire table and then either drop the `RRSOC_ID` column, or update it to null, or whatever new values you want.

Note that table constraints and triggers are not automatically recreated, so even if `RRSOC_ID` is a primary key in the original table you'll be able to set or change it to null in the new table.

Comment: for ur second answer, will it copy the data also ?

Comment: They will all copy data, yes, because I left out the `where 1=0` filter. Which you use depends on whether you want the column to not exist at all on the new table, or to exist but with all values null.

Comment: I am doing this `create table TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO as
select 
STORE_CODE, ...  from  TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO2;` but getting error as `SQL Error: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
00955. 00000 -  "name is already used by an existing object"`

Comment: Your original attempt was doing `create table TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO1`, so it had a different name to the source. Your earlier attempts may have created that (empty) table already too though, so you'd need to drop it before trying to create it again. But very carefully - make sure you're only dropping the new one, and that it doesn't actually have anything you need... You seem to have at least three table names now and it isn't clear what state any are in. You don't want to drop the original one with all the real data in it though.

Comment: see my main table is `TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO` and i have copied its data in `TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO2` so i dropped the main table and created by ur query. but i didn't got the values for `RRSOC_ID` as its primary key

Comment: OK... but isn't that what you wanted to happen? And as I said, if you use CTAS there the primary key is not recreated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161528/discussion-between-vvvv-and-alex-poole).